# Getac B300 Locked

Tags: bios, restore, ctrl-alt-delete

I bought this laptop from eBay but when it turns on its says Ctrl + Alt + Del and  then it says enter the password and user name. I'm not sure what I should do, I might have to get my money back but  I really love this laptop and I have many uses for it. Is there any way I can get past that or restore the settings. Please help!

Comment: Reinstall Windows.

Comment: Contact Getac customer support. Those Laptops are meant for millitary and I'm sure they have proper protection measures built-in which prevent methods like "remove the battery for 30 seconds" from working. I have a laptop and had a similar issue, while **nothing** worked, the customer support was able to generate a master BIOS password for me.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the CMOS Battery from the Motherboard.
Battery in hand, hold down the power button for 30 seconds, then leave standing for another 10 seconds.
Replace battery back into motherboard and the cmos should be reset.

Comment: This might work but please don't yell. I suggest you to edit your post

Comment: does not work on b300